# How to assign a hot key to a recorded macro in iMacros plugin of Firefox?

Tags: firefox, hotkeys, imacros

I have recorded a macro using iMacros plugin in Firefox. Does anyone know how can I assign a hotkey for it to use instead of clicking the play button? I am using Windows 10.